# split and table

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

> ```
>  GN  SN  
>   a   b   
>   a   b   
>   a   c   
>   d   e   
>   d   f 
>   d   e
> ```

I would like the following output:

GN: a  SN: 2 b  1 c
GN  d  SN: 2 e  1 f

In other words I would like to have a sort of table() of the data.frame on the column S.N. First of all I split the data.frame according to $GN, so I have blocks. At this point I' m not able to have the counting of the elements on column SN according to the split I've done. Is the "apply" function a way to do this? And how can I save a general output belonging from split function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your data:

```
df <- data.frame(GN = rep(c("a","b"), each = 3),
                 SN = c(rep("b", 2), "c", "e", "f", "e"))
```

We could do:

```
> lapply(with(df, split(SN, GN)), table)
$a

b c e f 
2 1 0 0 

$b

b c e f 
0 0 2 1
```

But if you don't want all the levels (the `0` entries) then we need to drop the empty levels:

```
> lapply(with(df, split(SN, GN)), function(x) table(droplevels(x)))
$a

b c 
2 1 

$b

e f 
2 1
```

### Writing out the individual tables to a file

This isn't perfect but at least you can work with it

```
## save tables
tmp <- lapply(with(df, split(SN, GN)), function(x) table(droplevels(x)))

## function to write output to file `fname`
foo <- function(x, fname) {
    cat(paste(names(x), collapse = " "), "\n", file = fname, append = TRUE)
    cat(paste(x, collapse = " "), "\n", file = fname, append = TRUE)
    invisible()
}

fname <- "foo.txt"
file.create(fname)                # create file fname
lapply(tmp, foo, fname = fname)   # run our function to write to fname
```

That gives:

```
R> readLines(fname)
[1] "b c " "2 1 " "e f " "2 1 "
```

or from the OS:

```
$ cat foo.txt
b c 
2 1 
e f 
2 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gavin! it works perfectly. How can I save the output of lapply since it is a list?

Comment: You can `saveRDS` the object as some R binary format, or you can loop through the list and write it to a file line by line, if you are after a text representation.

Comment: Hi Steve!Thank you very much! How can I write the output using for ex write.table?

Comment: You want to write out the tables to text? `lapply()` over the list. Will add an example.

Comment: Yes Gavin, I would like to display, for ex for a that b occurs two times and c 1 time, then that for b e occurs 2 times and f 1 time. All this, on the same file, non producing different output files.

Comment: Have added that example - not perfect but you asked for everything in one file...

Comment: Hi Gavin! Thank you so much! Even if not perfect, it saved my life...thank you again!